# DataGrid row header and column hiding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I set the row headers to be the first column of a binded `DataTable`:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="grdPreview"
              ItemsSource="{Binding PreviewData}"
              HeadersVisibility="All">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Row[0]}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

The problem is that the first column is still present and duplicates the row headers. How can I hide this column? Or maybe there is another way to display row headers?

**UPD:** You can see what I mean on the screenshot below: the first column `Spaltennamen` duplicates the row headers. What I want to achieve is to hide this column, likely without MVVM violation.

[image]

Comment: HeadersVisibility="Row"??

Comment: This will hide column headers, but not the column I don't want to be displayed.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve..

Comment: I want to hide the column that is taken to be the row headers. I'll update my post and add some screenshots to show what I mean

Comment: Yes you can hide it in code behind, but with MVVM, hmmm...

Comment: Code-behind is MVVM guys - if done correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGrid has an event [`AutoGeneratingColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn?view=netframework-4.8) that is fired for each generated column. In you xaml.cs file you do:

```
void myDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Spaltennamen")
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

All you need to do in XAML is to hook the event:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdPreview"
              AutoGeneratingColumn="myDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"
              ItemsSource="{Binding PreviewData}"
          HeadersVisibility="All">
```

This is not MVVM violation if you are concerned about that. If you don't want to hardcode the column name, you have extract the name from the rows or even have ViewModel property `IgnoredDataGridColumn` or something like that.